# Pointers as function returns and use of malloc

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, free

I am using Pointers as function returns ..below is a simple piece of code

**main function:**

```
void main()
{
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    int *ptr;
    ptr = add(&a, &b);
    printf("sum of a and b is %d\n", *ptr);
}
```

**add function:**

```
int* add(int *a, int *b)
{
    int c;
    c = *(a)+*(b);
    return &c;
}
```

This works correctly and gives me output  30..

But if you add one more function `printhelloworld();` before add like below

```
void main()
{
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    int *ptr;
    ptr = add(&a, &b);

    printhelloworld();--this just prints hello world

    printf("sum of a and b is %d\n", *ptr);
}
```

output will not be 30 any more and it is undefined due to stack frame getting freed..so I have to modify my program like below using `malloc()`

```
int* add(int *a, int *b)
{    
    int* c = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *c = *(a)+*(b);
    return c;
}
```

This works.

But if I don't free memory allocated in heap, won't it stay forever  ? Should I not use `free()` like below ?

```
free(c);
```

If I use `free()` in main,`c` is not in scope and it won't work, if I use 'free` in add, again I will get undefined result.

**ASK:**
What is the correct way to use `free()` in my case

```
free(C);
```

**Total program for repro**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void printhelloworld()
{

    printf("hello world\n");
}

int* add(int *a, int *b)
{

    int* c = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    *c = *(a)+*(b);
    //free(c);
    return c;
}


int main()
{

    int a = 10, b = 20;

    int *ptr;
    ptr =(int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    ptr = add(&a, &b);

printhelloworld();
printf("sum of a and b is %d\n", *ptr);

}
```

Comment: return of auto variable `return &c` which is temporary on the stack is Undefined behavior, or error. Soon will be overvritten

Comment: use the pointer returned as a parameter of the free function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> int* add(int *a, int *b)
> {
>     int c;
>     c = *(a)+*(b);
>     return &c;
> }
> ```
>
> This works correctly and gives me output 30..

This doesn't work, it just appears to in a simple case: `c` is a local variable, so the memory where the result of the addition is stored is released when the function returns. The memory used by the variable isn't wiped or reused immediately, so when you try to access it just after `add` returns, you get the value that you expected. However, when you call another function `printhelloworld`, it uses that same memory for its own local variables, and at some point the content of the memory gets updated.

Note that there's no guarantee that you'd see the result even in the simple case. A pointer usage hardening tool or a compiler optimization could cause the program to crash, display a different value, or behave in a bewildering manner at that point. C calls this “undefined behavior”.

If you want to allocate some memory in a function and return a pointer to it, then calling `malloc` in the function is correct. The memory allocated by `malloc` remains valid until you call `free` on it. Since you need to call `free` after you've finished using the memory, this has to happen after `add` returns: you do need to call `free` in `main`. Being able to call `malloc` and `free` from different functions is the whole point of dynamic memory allocation.

What you need to pass to `free` is the pointer value that `malloc` returns. You've assigned this value to `c`, and then you return `c` from `add`, so the address you need to pass to `free` is the value returned by `add`. The variable `ptr` in `main` contains the same value as the variable `c` in `free`. You can use it to access the value stored at this address, and you can also use it to free the block of memory.

```
int* add(int *a, int *b)
{    
    int* c = malloc(sizeof(int));  // no need for a cast here
    printf("The pointer is %p\n", (void*)c);
    if (c == NULL) { // Abort the program if the allocation failed
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *c = *(a)+*(b);
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    int *ptr;
    ptr = add(&a, &b);
    printf("The pointer is still %p\n", (void*)ptr);
    // ...
    printf("sum of a and b is %d\n", *ptr);
    free(ptr); // After this line, you aren't allowed to use the value of ptr any more
    ptr = NULL; // This is not necessary, but it's good practice to ensure that you won't accidentally use the value
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming `int` is a substitute for a more complex type.

You *could* allocate memory dynamically, and go down the rabbit hole of figuring out who has to free it.

Alternatively, you can let the caller of `add` decide where the new object should be allocated. You can accept a pointer to an object, where `add` should then write:

```
void add(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{    
    *c = *(a)+*(b);
}
```

Now the calling code can easily decide to use an automatic variable:

```
int c;
add(&a, &b, &c);
```

And not worry about dynamic allocation if it doesn't need it. It makes for easier to maintain code IMO, due to the reduced responsibility of `add`.

Comment: Great example,Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> If I use free() in main,c is not in scope and it won't work, if I use 'free` in add, again I will get undefined result.

The scope of the local variable `c` in `add()` isn't relevant; you still have access to the malloc'ed pointer in main in `ptr`. So you can free it in main():

```
free(ptr);
```

All that matters to `free()` is that the value is returned by a previous dynamic allocation (`malloc`/`realloc`/`calloc` etc) - it doesn't have to be through the same variable.

Comment: Great point`All that matters to free() is that the value is returned by a previous dynamic allocation` Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although your variable `c` will run out of scope, the correct way of controlling dynamically allocated memory is to save its address to a variable in any scope and calling `free()` on that variable whenever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main()
```

`main` shpould return an `int`. Please make sure you use one of the two definitions of `main`:

```
int main(void)
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

Other definitions are not portable.

```
return &c;
```

Returning an address of a local variable is **undefined**. An implementation is allowed to do anything with this program, including making it appear to work on 17th day of each month.

> What is the correct way to use free() in my case

The right thing to do is not to use pointers when not needed, but if you do use a pointer, then free it in the `main` function like this:

```
ptr = add(&a, &b);
...  
free(ptr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and portability,i didn't know that about `main`

Comment: Actually, returning an address of a local variable is quite defined, however, dereferencing that address afterwards leads to undefined behavior.